# Creating a simple unit test troubles in an MVC3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd

Here is the unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Index_GET_Asks_For_Index_View()
    {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        ViewResult result = controller.Index();
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Basically I want to make sure when I visit the Index action method that I invoke the correct view. However, the test fails and I don't know why.

> ------ Test started: Assembly: Demo.Tests.dll ------
>
> Test
>   'Demo.Tests.HomeControllerTests.Index_GET_Asks_For_Index_View'
>   failed:
>
> Expected string length 5 but was 0. Strings differ at index 0.
>
> Expected: "Index"
>
> But was:     -----------^  HomeControllerTests.cs(19,0): at
>   Demo.Tests.HomeControllerTests.Index_GET_Asks_For_Index_View()

Here is the actual controller code:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "This is just a demo.";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: It looks like by your expectation, you really have a string length of zero, which makes `ViewName` appear to be an empty string.  My guess would be that the resolution of the `ViewName` when empty, resolves to the correct `ViewName` after this.

Comment: See my answer.  `ViewName` is going to be empty 11 times out of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this reference with an empty call to View()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460331.aspx).  Here is a quote from that MSDN article:

> This method overload of the `View` class returns a `ViewResult` object
>   that has an **empty `ViewName` property**. *If you are writing unit tests for
>   controller actions, take into account the empty ViewName property for
>   unit tests that do not take a string view name.*

Comment: Ok, so the solution is that in your controller, instead of doing `return View()` you need to go `return View("Index")` being explicit. The test passes fine now. Thank you!

Comment: @SergioTapia, no, this is not the solution. The solution is to assert that the view name is an empty string in your unit test: `Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, result.ViewName);` which according to the documentation would mean that the controller action returned the default view. Quote: `take into account the empty ViewName property for unit tests that do not take a string view name`

Comment: I agree with Darin's recommendation.  Even in TDD you shouldn't have to write repetitive code just so a unit test succeeds.  Write the unit test to it succeeds.  Great recommendation on Darin.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Thank you. I fixed that and will keep it in mind for the future. :)